# python re.split() to split by spaces, commas, and periods, but not in cases like 1,000 or 1.50

Tags: python, regex

I want to use python `re.split()` to split a string into individual words by spaces, commas and periods. But I don't want `"1,200"` to be split into `["1", "200"]` or `["1.2"]` to be split into `["1", "2"]`.

Example

```
l = "one two 3.4 5,6 seven.eight nine,ten"
```

The result should be `["one", "two", "3.4", "5,6" , "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead and a negative lookbehind:

```
> s = "one two 3.4 5,6 seven.eight nine,ten"
> parts = re.split('\s|(?<!\d)[,.](?!\d)', s)
['one', 'two', '3.4', '5,6', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten']
```

In other words, you always split by `\s` (whitespace), and only split by commas and periods if they are **not** followed `(?!\d)` or preceded `(?<!\d)` by a digit.

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/FyS9m)**.

**EDIT**: As per @verdesmarald comment, you may want to use the following instead:

```
> s = "one two 3.4 5,6 seven.eight nine,ten,1.2,a,5"
> print re.split('\s|(?<!\d)[,.]|[,.](?!\d)', s)
['one', 'two', '3.4', '5,6', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', '1.2', 'a', '5']
```

This will split `"1.2,a,5"` into `["1.2", "a", "5"]`.

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/wYZIb)**.

Comment: I think the OP actually wants not followed *and* proceeded, rather than or, so it should be `(?<!\d)[.,]|[.,](?!\d)` not `(?<!\d)[,.](?!\d)`. E.g. I suspect `"1.2,a"` should become `["1.2", "a"]`.

Comment: @verdesmarald: You may be right indeed, I've edited my answer to reflect that, thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50463669/special-regex-for-string-in-python#50463935

Answer (score 3):

So you want to split on spaces, and on commas and periods that aren't surrounded by numbers. This should work:

```
r" |(?<![0-9])[.,](?![0-9])"
```