# Replace non alphanumeric characters except some exceptions python

Tags: python, regex, alphanumeric

In perl `s/[^\w:]//g` would replace all non alphanumeric characters **EXCEPT :**

In python I'm using `re.sub(r'\W+', '',mystring)`
which does remove all non alphanumeric except _ underscore.
Is there any way to put exceptions, I wish not to replace signs like = and .

Previously I was applying the other approach i.e. to replace all unwanted characters using`re.sub('[!@#\'\"`$()]', '',mystring`)
However, it is not possible for me to predict what all characters may come in mystring hence I wish to remove all non alphanumeric characters except a few.

Google didnt provide an appropriate answer. The closest search being [python regex split any \W+ with some exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458601/python-regex-split-any-w-with-some-exceptions) but this didnt help me either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can specify everything that you  need not remove in the negated character clas.

```
re.sub(r'[^\w'+removelist+']', '',mystring)
```

**Test**

```
>>> import re
>>> removelist = "=."
>>> mystring = "asdf1234=.!@#$"
>>> re.sub(r'[^\w'+removelist+']', '',mystring)
'asdf1234=.'
```

Here the `removelist` variable is a string which contains the list of all characters you need to exclude from the removal.

**What does negated character class means**

When the `^` is moved into the character class it does not acts as an anchor where as it negates the character class.

That is `^` in inside a character class say like `[^abc]` it negates the meaning of the character class.

For example `[abc]` will match `a` `b` or `c` where as `[^abc]` will not match `a` `b` or `c`. Which can also be phrased as *anything other than `a` `b` or `c`*

Comment: thanks @nu11p01n73R . I was not adding remove list inside, [] . I gave something like '^w.=' which off course was not working. Could you please tell the meaning of r and ^, ^ is usually used as "start with" but here it seems to be having a different meaning.

Comment: @user1977867 Yep when `^` in inside a character class say like `[^abc]` it negates the meaning of the character class. That is `[abc]` will match `a` `b` or `c` where as `[^abc]` will not match `a` `b` or `c`. That is anything other than `a` `b` or `c`

Comment: Can I ask why you're calling removelist 'remove'list? It seems to me that it's a list of chars that you'd like to keep. I'm only mentioning it because it had me confused.

Comment: @ikku100 Ohh, I have mentioned it in the answer *Here the removelist variable is a string which contains the list of all characters you need to exclude from the removal.*

Answer (score 10):

```
re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9=]', '',mystring)
```

You can add whatever you want like `_` whichever you want to save.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the approach you describe in perl could also be used in python, eg:

```
re.sub(r'[^\w=]', '',mystring)
```

would remove everything except word-characters and =