# Special regex for String in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string like below.

> s = ({[test1, test2 ; test3 (New) ]})

Now I have a regex which will remove brackets and convert it into the list. Even if there are separated with a;b,c like.
REGEX:

```
output = [i for i in re.split(r'\s*[(){}<>\[\],;\'"]\s*', s) if i]
```

But this regex is removing brackets from items of the list as well. (**(New)** in my case)

How to apply this regex for beginnig and end of the string. I know it can be done using `^` but not sure how?

**Expected Output**

> ['test1', 'test2', 'test3 (New)' ]

**Output coming from above regex**

> ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'New']

Any help?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Is adding the brackets to the list element an option ? Is the `(New)` element always the last in the list ?

Comment: No, I mean there may be `(New)` something like this in any element of my string. I want to remove brackets only from starting and end of string

Comment: @JayeshDhandha, what should be the result for this string `-[({[test1, test2(3) ; test3 (New) ]})]-`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = '({[test1, test2 ; test3 (New) ]})'
```

Based on your comment below I assume that the number of opening brackets of the whole string is equal to the number of closing brackets.

So removing the outer brackets first needs to know their number:

```
m = re.match('[({[]*', s)
n_brckt = m.span()[1] - m.span()[0]
```

Then remove the outer brackets ( - dependent on if there were found any...):

```
if n_brckt > 0:
    s = s[n_brckt:-n_brckt]
s = s.strip()

In: s
Out: 'test1, test2 ; test3 (New)'
```

Then you can split at all occurences of commas or colons optionally followed by a space:

```
In: re.split('[,;]+ *', s)
Out: ['test1', 'test2', 'test3 (New)']
```

Comment: I can't use `strip` as there may be different number of brackets in the starting and ending of string. I can't use `string with 3 count`

Comment: So how _do_ the beginning and the end of the strings look like? This should be made clear, otherwise it's just a guessing game...

Comment: Its not fix. Sometimes it has `[{( ` and sometimes `[{` only.
And same thing at the end of string.

Comment: You have missed 1 thing. If my string doesn't contain any brackets then your output will be `['']`
Which is not right.

Comment: Do you want to tell me, that the string might even have no outer brackets at all...?

Comment: Yes. We have to see all the corner case :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `re.search`

```
import re
s = "({[test1, test2 ; test3 (New) ]})"
m = re.search("\[(.*?)\]", s)
if m:
    #print(m.group(1).replace(";", ",").split(",")) 
    print([i.strip() for i in m.group(1).replace(";", ",").split(",")])
```

**Output:**

```
['test1', 'test2', 'test3 (New)']
```

Comment: Good Answer. Thanks!

Comment: Check output for `(({{[[test1, test2 ; test3 (France)]]}}))`

Comment: For a deep nested structure, regex will not work and can cause unwanted issues. It is best to find a parser according to your need. Ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454322/python-how-to-match-nested-parentheses-with-regex

Comment: Please note that `if m:` is not a valid test for success of `re.match`. You _could_ use `if m.end():` but however, clearly writing `if m.end() > 0:` or sth similar is always clearer to read and understand immediately.