# How to re.split(" ", string) when there are multiple spaces?

Tags: python, regex, split

```
d = ["11:00 PM", "13!00 PM", "11 00 PM"]

for i in d:
    print(re.split(" ", i)
```

For others it's okay, prints `["11:00", "PM"]` and `["13!00", "PM"]`, but for `11 00 PM` it prints `["11", "00", "PM"]`. How can I change the regex so it would return `["11 00", "PM"]` there too?

Comment: use normal split - `"11 00 PM".rsplit(' ', 1)` - it means `i.rsplit(' ', 1)`

Comment: You could try a more advanced regex, perhaps something like here (check out the demos!): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683201/python-re-split-to-split-by-spaces-commas-and-periods-but-not-in-cases-like

Comment: Or simply: `print(re.split("\s+(?=AM|PM)", i))` which is being a little bit more specific, asserting that we only split next to AM/PM

Answer (score 7):

For these examples you can use normal `text.split()` (or rather `text.rsplit()`) instead of `regex`

```
d = ["11:00 PM", "13!00 PM", "11 00 PM"]

for i in d:
    print(i.rsplit(" ", 1))
```

Result:

```
['11:00', 'PM']
['13!00', 'PM']
['11 00', 'PM']
```

---

**EDIT:**

if you want to remove "white chars" - space, tab, enter - at both sides then you can use normal `text.strip()`. Similar `rstrip()` and `lstrip()` for right or left side. Or use `strip(' ')` if you want to remove only spaces and keep tabs and enters.

```
i = i.strip().rsplit(" ", 1)
```

---

```
d = [" 11:00 PM", "\n 13!00 PM", "11 00 PM"]

for i in d:
    print(i.strip().rsplit(" ", 1))
```

---

**EDIT:** If you want to keep result then you can append to list

```
d = [" 11:00 PM", "\n 13!00 PM", "11 00 PM"]

results = []    

for i in d:
    results.append(i.strip().rsplit(" ", 1))

print(results)
```

or you can use list comprehension as @Alexander said in comment

```
d = [" 11:00 PM", "\n 13!00 PM", "11 00 PM"]

results = [x.strip().rsplit(maxsplit=1) for x in d]

print(results)
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that some of those strings may have whitespace/newline before them. How to get rid of those then?
```
[" 11:00 PM", "\n 13!00 PM", "11 00 PM"]

Comment: `rsplit()` check spaces from right to left so spaces at the beginning make no difference. But if you want to remove spaces at right end `i = i.rstrip()`, on left end `i = i.lstrip()`, on both ends `i = i.strip()` and later use `rsplit()` - or both `i = i.strip().rsplit(" ", 1)`

Comment: Or using a list comprension: `[x.strip().rsplit(maxsplit=1) for x in d]`

Comment: @Alexander good point - I added your list comprension to answer.